# Create polygon on a map in right projection using R

Tags: r, shapes, projection

In my project I am using different projections for my data. I want to learn what happens when you create shapes in a equivalent (equal area) projection and transform them to a conformal projection.

I have a SPDF in an equal area projection. I am trying to create some shapes in this SPDF to later transform them. I did not expect that this is a difficult task. I would like to work with vectors.

The main problem I think I have is that I am unaware of the package and function I should use. I have searched for a couple of hours this morning but can not find the right package or function. Also I can not find people asking questions about this exact topic, which surprises me.

So the question is: How do I make a shape in a SPDF using R?

Comment: See http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Teaching/UseR2012/cheatsheet.html and http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/intro_sp.pdf

Comment: Is it relevant to the question that you are using RStudio?

Comment: I have no idea. I guess so because people know where I am working in. Or should I just have used R for that?